# Passing data from Native android to React Native

Tags: android, react-native, mobile

I am trying to establish a communication between the native part (android) with javascript part(react-native).Here is the following code from Java side:-

```
WritableMap params = Arguments.createMap();
                    params.putString("arg1","valueToJS");
                    getReactApplicationContext().getJSModule(DeviceEventManagerModule.RCTDeviceEventEmitter.class)
                            .emit("showResult",params);
```

And the Respective Javascript file to receive the event :-

```
  DeviceEventEmitter.addListener('showResult', function (e: Event) {   
        // hadle the event triggered from java side
    });
```

Now in addListner where do we add the params(Argument) in order to get the "valueToJS",Since i am not able find proper documentation about DeviceEventEmitter i am finding difficult to get the value of argument arg1.Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: I guess you will get it in  variable `e`, try to print it out

Comment: thanks Ravi i got the vale but any idea on how to get the value from event object i tried e.target.value but its undefined

{ arg1: ''valueToJS' }

Comment: not sure about it

Comment: May be i was too dump.Solved by :-
`e.arg1`